# Why does F# impose a low limit on stack size?

Tags: recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I would like to know if there is a fundamental reason for limiting the depth of recursion in F# to 10000 or so, and ideally how to avoid that limit. I think it is perfectly reasonable to write code that uses O(n) stack space, and would be grateful if someone who disagrees could explain why they do. Many thanks. I explain my thinking below.

I don't see that there is any reason for not allowing the stack to grow until the entire available memory is exhausted. It would mean infinite recursion would take longer to notice, but it's not as if we cannot already write programs that consume an infinite amount of memory. I am aware it is possible to reduce stack usage to O(1) using continuations and tail recursion, but I don't particularly see how it is good for me to have to do that all the time. Neither do I see how it helps to have to know when a function is likely to need to process a "large" input (well, by the standards of an 8-bit micro-controller).

I think this is fundamentally different from having to e.g. use accumulating parameters to avoid quadratic time behavior. While that too involves worrying about implementation details, and does not need to be done for "small" inputs, it is also very different in that the compiler cannot trivially remove the problem on its own. It is furthermore different in that slightly complicated O(n) code that would have been O(n^2) if written naively is very substantially more useful than the simple, slow, easy-to-read version. In contrast, continuation-style code has exactly the same memory complexity as the corresponding naive version, but just uses a different kind of memory. This is the sort of a thing the compiler should not make me worry about in this day and age?

While I would "prefer" a theoretical reason for why it is not possible to have a deep stack, we might as well discuss practical aspects too. It seems to me that a stack is a somewhat more efficient way of managing memory than the heap in that it does not require garbage collection and is easily freed? I am not sure I can even see there is a cost to allowing deep stacks. Admittedly, the OS needs to set aside enough virtual space to contain all the memory you might want to use at once in the whole program for every thread's stack. But so what. It's not as if we are likely to run out of the currently common 48-bit limit by doing that, or that hardware manufacturers cannot trivially increase that limit to 64-bits?

There is not that much specific to F# here. I expect the same restriction applies in C#, and don't see that it is any more necessary there, although it is obviously a lot less of a pain in practice when programming in imperative style.

Many thanks for any replies/comments.

EDIT: I wrote a summary of the answers below.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this isn't unique to F#; Python also has a recursion limit (a depth limit of 1000 or 10000 I think).

Comment: In Python, the limit is around 1000 (not 10000). Yet we get along just fine. Why require O(n) stack space when you can have O(1) memory consumption? Could you show an example that requires hundreds of recursive calls and cannot be rewritten easily to a loop?

Comment: Could you provide a reference for F# limiting the depth of recursion to 10000? My understanding was that the CLR didn't have a fixed max stack size and instead the max stack size was based on the amount of memory available. The F# compiler also rewrites many forms of recursion so that stack space isn't consumed.

Comment: @WesleyWiser, under normal circumstances, the stack of each .Net thread is limited to 1 MB.

Comment: Delnan: I cannot. All code can be rewritten to use O(1) stack space. The point I am making is that i) it then becomes harder to read and maintain, and ii) it's the compiler's job to do the conversion (or should be).

Comment: @user1002059: I know. That's why I included a "easily". For example, I see the merit of writing depth-first tree traversal "naively", i.e. with recursion. But a `fold`- or `map`-esque operation is trivial to write as `for` loop and the result is just as easy to read and reason about.

Comment: @delnan: Mutual recursion can be hard to rewrite as a loop because the functions calling each other recursively can be in separate assemblies.

Comment: As a completely random aside, I discovered by accident that the stack size limit on Mono is considerably higher than in .net (although still not the full amount of memory available).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, anything is possible.  You could write a compiler that uses the heap to manage what is traditionally 'stack'.

In practice, performance (especially for fundamentals like 'function calls') matters.  We've got a half-century of hardware and operating system tailored/optimized for the finite stack memory model.

> This is the sort of a thing the compiler should not make me worry about in this day and age?

Meh.  Garbage collection is a big win; managing all your memory is a mostly-needless chore, and many applications can trade-off some performance for the programmer productivity here.  But I think few people feel that human-managing of stack/recursion is a huge deal, even in functional language, so the value of letting the programmer off the hook here is, IMO, marginal.

Note that in F# specifically, you can use a CPS workflow that will transform a fair bit of stack into heap and/or tail-calls, with a relatively minor change in programming style/syntax, if you want to go there (see e.g. [here](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/catamorphisms-part-seven/)).

Comment: True, but i) it is unclear there is any cost whatsoever to allowing large stacks on x86-64, and the cost on other architectures seems to be trivial (i.e. a small constant factor, and then only if you use large stacks), and ii) I am pretty sure that using CPS everywhere would be a big deal as regards clarity and maintainability, if only because it unnecessarily imposes a particular evaluation order.

Comment: Large stacks do make a huge difference, at least for large scale concurrent server apps.  All the 'async' hype you hear is pretty much about this; the main reason threads are expensive is because they take so much memory, and the reason threads take so much memory is that they have a megabyte of stack (or whatever) reserved for them.  The more memory you leave for the stack, the fewer threads you can have before running the process/system out of memory.  (That said, for non-scale or client apps that don't need many threads, sure, just make a huge stack size, and you're fine.)

Comment: I wonder if the bit about threads needing 1M of stack is right. There is a lot of difference between allocating the virtual space and the physical memory. I think the most you need waste on the X86-64 is one 4k physical page per stack?

Comment: @user1002069, in terms of .NET, it is the memory.  You're possibly right about the OS-level allocation, but this is a .NET limit; each thread does consume a meg of the .NET address space, and the .NET address space does have a hard limit.

Comment: @user1002059: "it is unclear there is any cost whatsoever to allowing large stacks on x86-64, and the cost on other architectures seems to be trivial (i.e. a small constant factor, and then only if you use large stacks)". No, large stacks asymptotically degrade the throughput and latency of the GC unless special measures are taken, measures that would decrease performance by a substantial constant factor everywhere.

Comment: Brian: why would I care about how much .net address space is used? I appreciate there is a 32 bit limit on the size of everything, but that can be increased in principle, and the stack size limit is a tiny fraction of that in any case. I know very little about the internals of .net, but it seems to me that if the size of its address space is the limiting factor then it is an arbitrary restriction without a fundamental reason?

Comment: There's a finite amount of address space in a 32-bit .NET process.  Each thread swallows a not-insubstantial-sized chunk of that address space for its stack reserve.  As a result, with typical-size stacks, you can only have about a thousand threads in .NET before you run out of space to address the thread stacks.  This has been the major bottleneck for creating simple large-scale server apps.  The larger your stack size, the fewer threads you can fit in the process.  (Which is why non-blocking async is so important for server apps: more CPU work with fewer threads.)

Answer (score 9):

By far the most compelling reason for F# to inherit the limitations of .NET in this context is compatibility. Compilers can and do completely eliminate the stack, e.g. the SML/NJ compiler for Standard ML transforms programs into continuation passing style automatically. The two main disadvantages are that it requires a global change to the calling convention that breaks compatibility and that it is substantially less efficient. If F# did this to evade stack overflows then C# interoperability would be a lot harder and F# would be a lot slower.

Another reason why deep stacks are a bad idea is the garbage collector. Stacks are treated specially by GCs because they are guaranteed to be thread local and can shrink without requiring collection. The .NET GC traverses all thread stacks whenever any thread incurs a gen0 collection. Consequently, having just two sleeping threads with deep stacks can make another thread run 10x slower. Imagine how much worse that would be with much deeper stacks. This can be solved by changing the way the GC treats the stacks, essentially turning them into heaps, but that makes stack operations a lot slower.

Comment: This is a very good answer, and one that I had not though of. Many thanks. However I don't see why every stack could not come with a marker that says "from here up, all references are to gen 1/gen 2" objects. That would presumably preserve constant amortised cost of processing stack elements even with an unbounded stack?

Comment: You can pass mutables on the stack by reference so you can mutate pointers further up the stack to point into freshly allocated objects in gen0. Consequently, quite a bit of extra work must be performed to keep your markers up-to-date and, therefore, the technique is a bit slower. Other GCs do this though, e.g. some JVMs. However, the .NET GCs have other shortcomings that I would prefer to see addressed first.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid that limit easily: just start a new thread that has a stack as big as you want using [an overload of constructor for `Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks. The only fly in the ointment is that the constructor takes an int, so there is a 2G/4G limit. The code will run on a 96G server, so I would really like a limit about that size :-)

Comment: @user1002059 : That is a fundamental .NET restriction; there's no way around it with managed code, F# or otherwise.

Comment: @user1002059 If you ever tried working with larger stacks you will notice that your whole process becomes slower. What wasn't mentioned in the answers is that stacks should not grow beyond hardware limits for cpu caches. it removes predictability. It's easy to show by running performance tests with stack sizes increased dramatically (try 100mb for instance). This is not only a .net behavioural limit but imposed by hardware design and limitations on algorithms in cpu cache hit design.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of at least two possible reasons:

(1) On many computer architectures, it's hard to increase the size available for the stack at runtime without moving it somewhere else in the address space. As @svick pointed out in the comments, .NET on 32 bit Windows limits the main thread's stack size to 1MB. Changing the main thread's stack size on Windows requires a change to the .EXE file.

(2) It is FAR, FAR more common for a stack overflow to be caused by a programming error than by actually having code that genuinely needs to exceed the available stack size. A limited stack size is a very useful sentinel to catch programming errors. In 98% of cases, if the stack were allowed to grow to available memory, the first time you'd find out about your programming errors would be when you exhausted available memory.

Comment: (1) I am not sure that is relevant. Moving the stack somewhere else is only necessary if you did not allocate enough virtual space to start with, and there is no shortage of it on 64-bit architectures. Even then, moving it would not require a physical copy, just remapping the virtual memory somewhere else. And even with an O(n) copy, stack operations would still be O(1) amortised time. In any case, all this relates to the CPU stack. DotNET uses IL that could easily store its stack in a datastructure that grows easily (maybe something like C++ deque).

Comment: (2) That is not my experience. In any case, the low limit is a source of runtime crashes that are difficult to predict and that are triggered just by the user supplying a slightly larger input than the code was tested with. Besides, I suspect it only catches errors that would be caught anyway, except after using a bit more memory.

Comment: @user1002059: "DotNET uses IL that could easily store its stack in a datastructure that grows easily (maybe something like C++ deque)". Those data structures are substantially (like 50%) slower than a "raw" stack.

Comment: Jon Harrop: Yes, but that would only matter for programs that would otherwise crash? I really could not care about losing 50% of runtime performance if that meant i) not needing to stick continuations everywhere, and ii) not having to worry I missed somewhere (which is remarkably easy to do).

Answer (score 2):

I think this has now had as many answers as it is going to get. Here is a summary:

i) no-one suggested any fundamental reason for a stack-limit lower than the total amount of available memory

ii) the answer that I learned the most form was Brian's (many thanks). I would strongly recommend the blog post that he linked, and the rest of his blog too. I found it more informative than either of the two good books on F# I have. (Having said that, you should probably have a look at what he says about just how straightforward it is to achieve tail recursion in part 6 of the blog posts on catamorphisms https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/catamorphisms-part-six/ before you take the word "marginal" he had used at face value :-) ).

EDIT: Jon Harrop was a very close second. Many thanks.

iii) Svick suggested an easy way of increasing the limit by three orders of magnitude. Many thanks.

iv) Delnan suggested the best practice is to just use folds/maps everywhere, and define those in a tail-recursive way. This is certainly sound advice for lists, but perhaps less applicable when traversing graphs. Either way, many thanks for the suggestion.

v) Joel and Brian suggested some practical reasons for why the limit is a good idea. They were all low-level details that I feel should be well hidden by a high-level language. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the stack wont be an issue if you write your functions to be tail recursive